# Choose value for $_FILES[<filename>]["tmp_name"]

Tags: php

Is there a way to client-side choose the value for `$_FILES[<filename>]["tmp_name"]` instead of having it be randomly generated?  For example, is there some type of attribute I can somehow append to the file itself, called "tmp_name", so that when it's uploaded the receiving PHP script reads **my** `tmp_name` rather than generating a random one?

Comment: the temp name is just that, temporary, why do you need to change its name?

Comment: I'm working on an educational challenge that involves exploiting web vulnerabilities, and I noticed in the code that if I am able to somehow set `tmp_name` myself, I can get the password to the next level.  It has nothing to do with the file or script itself.

Comment: ah, fair enough, then no, as @deceze says below, I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The uploaded file data is stored in a *temporary file* which is *randomly named*. And it's good that the user has no influence on that, it could be a security issue if he did. You [can configure the directory in which this temporary file will be created in your php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir), but that's all.

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't hugely shock me, since the question came up as part of a web vulnerability challenge.  Hence your point about it being a security vulnerability is exactly why I wanted that ability.